# Почему не выводит реальную ширину?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вывожу в консоле

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('wmd-view'))
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('wmd-view')[0].scrollWidth)
```

в хроме выводится вот что

> 1. [div.col-lg-12.wmd-view] [0]:div.col-lg-12.wmd-view scrollWidth: 1347
> 2. 1307

Почему так? У родительского элемента `wmd-view` ширина 1307. Как мне вывести вот этот 1347

Answer (score 1):

jquery

```
$('.wmd-view').outerWidth(true)
```

для родительского элемента

```
$('.wmd-view').parent().outerWidth(true);
```

Comment: не работает, все перепробовал, innerWidth, outerWidth, offsetWidth

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net можете воспроизвести тут или дать ссылку на проект?

Comment: не могу, проект внутренний, с внешной стороны доступа нет. А в jsfiddle по другому отображается

Comment: .wmd-view этот класс один на странице или несколько? если несколько тогда укажите явно на нужный вам экземпляр. больше затрудняюсь сказать не видя страницы.

Comment: а в какой момент вы выводите console.log? может у вас еще не все загрузилось? $(window).load(function(){ console.log()  })

Comment: даже если так но я же делаю один за одним сразу, в одном 1347 в другом 1307. никакого margin || padding нет